# Help identify these capacitors

Tags: capacitor, markings

Could you give me more info on these capacitors?
My guess is
Top = 50pF
Bottom = 15000pF = 15nF

Correct?
What is the meaning of remaining char?
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: They are both 15 nF but one is 100 volt rated and the top one is likely 50 volt rated.

Comment: In addition to the correct answer from DerStrom8, they are polyester (aka Mylar®) film dipped capacitors with radial leads.

Answer (score 2):

I can only assume that the label of the top one is "50K.015" (with the 5 partially rubbed off), which would be 0.015uF (15nF), 50V, with a 10% tolerance ("K"). The one on the bottom is 15,000pF (15nF), 100V. A tolerance value does not appear to be indicated.

Tolerance markings:
[image]

Comment: Super thanks to both of you! So quick and clear!